# QtCreator debug pause stop at code not assembly

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

How can I configure QtCreator so that when I'm debugging and I press pause it would show the code it is currently processing (now it shows assembly). Couldn't find an answer anywhere about this.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem with Qt Creator 4.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. One of the steps can solve your problem:

1. Try to swith compile mode in the left corner to `Debug` mode
2. Try to switch off option `Debug->Operate by instruction`, when you debugging. But it doesn't work for me.
3. Try to switch option `Tools->Debugger->Set breakpoint using full absolute path`.
4. Try to add your Qt Src path in window `Source Path Mapping` (`Tools->Debugger->Add Qt sources`)
5. Use only ASCII symbols in your 'project' and 'build' directory paths.

After step 5, there was magic and gdb sucess work in src mode.

Answer (score 0):

It might not have the sources for the code it is currently executing. It could be in a system DLL, for instance. If you look at the stack trace, you might find a function that it has the source for, but this is not guaranteed -- it could be in a thread for which no source is available at all.

Comment: So how can I debug using QtCreator then?? Explicitly, I want to see where my program loops itself. If I could find out which line it stays I know where it loops.

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace? Do you know where that is?

Comment: If I can see it under Windows->Stack, then yes. Else please tip me.

Comment: OK, now set a breakpoint in your code, and run to the breakpoint. You should see source code now. And in the Stack view, a list of all the functions in the call stack.

Comment: So what do you see in the Stack view when you pause the running program?

Comment: Yes, I can see the call stack. I'm not sure though this will help me out. Imagine this: you have a program which processes something. However, sometimes it loops forever due to the circumstances. Obviously, to find where it loops one would let the program run until there is response on the screen and after sometime of no response he would pause the execution and debugger SHOULD display on which line he currently paused in code thus giving him a notion of where the error might be. This I can't do wit QtC, since it only displays disassembler.