# Qt Creator: unable to switch off disassembly view in debugger

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, ubuntu, qt-creator

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.10. I tried to debug one of my projects in C++/Qt in Qt Creator 4.0.2, that comes in official Ubuntu repository.

For some reason, when I set breakpoint in source code and launch debugging, Qt Creator stops at breakpoint, but only in disassembly view. "Operate by Instruction" is disabled. However I have tried both ways. It seems like debugger cannot find sources for this build, but in previous system version (I think Qt Creator 3.6.x was default) I did everything the same and it worked. I also have this problem on Kubuntu 16.10.

My build/bin directory is within project root. I have also tried disabling shadow build. Nothing worked.

My system is brand new, I have minimal set to download project with git and compile it.

Project/system configuration:
- Ubuntu 16.10 x86-64
- gcc 6.2.0
- gdb 7.11.90
- qt creator 4.0.2
- qt 5.6.1
- git 2.9.3

```
kuba@chimera:~ :) $ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Comment: Is this the thing where you're in debugging mode and you can't get the debugging windows to go away and then you click `Edit` on the left toolbar and everything goes back to normal?

Comment: I don't understand "get the debugging windows to go away". When I'm at the breakpoint I can switch normally to Edit mode, but dissablemly is still visible (as opened document). Switching between Debug and Edit mode only closes right "Variable Watch" toolbar and bottom "callstack" and "breakpoints" toolbars.

Comment: Are you actually doing a _debug_ build of your project?

Comment: Yes, debug was the only version I selected when project was configured. Also I can see -g option passed to gcc, so this is 100% debug version.

Comment: I had this problem, but I was able to solve it:
[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43596066/7557704)