# How to switch off disassembler in Qt Debug?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator, fedora

when I try to set a breakpoint and debug I see the disassemler view. I tried to google the way to switch it off but these advices couldn't help. **I have a debug regime and no tick near "Debug -> Operate by Instruction"**

[image]

so, **I couldn't find the way to hide the disassembler screen**

[image]

**I have only ASCII symbols in my 'project' and 'build' directory paths**.

Tools->Debugger->Set breakpoint using full absolute path **is switched on**.
**Source path to project is added to Source Paths Mapping.**

How to fix it?...
I have QtCreator v. 4.5.0 (based on Qt v. 5.9.2), OS is Fedora 27.

Comment: Have you got source file(s) of the application you debug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QtCreator debug pause stop at code not assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585204/qtcreator-debug-pause-stop-at-code-not-assembly)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007516/qt-creator-unable-to-switch-off-disassembly-view-in-debugger

Comment: @vahancho do you mean the path to my project in Tools->Debugger->General->Source Path Mapping? Yes, I try to add it here, but the problem remains.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit yes, I saw these threads but they couldn't help me(

Comment: I had a Cyrillic letter in the project path... it was treacherous. After really Latin path setting the problem was solved.

Comment: About "I had a Cyrillic letter in the project path... it was treacherous. After really Latin path setting the problem was solved" I ended up reporting a bug report that has been solved today: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-24462